# Можно ли в .NET безопасно хранить учетные данные?

Tags: c#, .net, безопасность

Например, обычная ситуация, когда для доступа к какому-то внешнему ресурсу нужна учетная запись.

Можно захардкодить ее в коде, но это не безопасно, так как .NET приложение можно декомпилировать и узнать эти данные.

1. Есть ли способы безопасного хранения учетных данных непосредственно в коде C# или конфигах?
2. Какие есть альтернативы такому хардкодингу?

Comment: А разве для этих целей внешний сервис не предоставляет какой-то аутентификационный токен?

Comment: @sp7, сервисы бывают разными...

Comment: Как будто нативное приложение нельзя декомпилировать :)

Answer (score 5):

Способа безопасно спрятать учетные данные так, чтобы пользователь не смог их извлечь и использовать вне вашей программы, не существует. Даже если вы прикрутите какую-то хитрую схему шифрования, которая, возможно, защитит от декомпиляции - вы не сможете защититься от отладки / трассировки.

Т.е. пользователь всегда может просто взять и перехватить вызов того же `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()` (и любого другого способа работы см удаленным ресурсом), и достать сырые имя и пароль из заголовков или тела запроса. Или еще проще - он может поставить fiddler и просто просмотреть траффик.

То же самое касается любых других видов соединения - от SQL Server до самописных протоколов. Точно так же нельзя "спрятать" имя и пароль от SQL Server при подключении к SQL напрямую из desktop app.

---

Единственный надежный способ спрятать данные от пользователя - не отдавать их на сторону пользователя вообще. Сделайте свой сервис, с собственным механизмом аутентификации, и пропускайте запросы к стороннему сервису через него.

Comment: `"Единственный надежный способ спрятать данные..."` -- не понимаю, что тут в корне усложнило перехват механизма аутентификации с последующим его использованием хакером (пользователем)? Или вы предлагаете запускать программу не на стороне пользователя (что спрашивает ТС) а на доверенном удаленном сервере?

Comment: @avp я предлагаю перенести кусок кода для работы с внешнеми ресурсом (которому нужна учетка, которую нельзя видель пользователю) со стороны пользователя на доверенный сервер. Т.е. например не лезть из WinForms в SQL Server напрямую под sa (что позволяет пользователю вытащить пароль от SQL и полезть напрямую в базу), а перенести код работы с SQL в вебсервис.

Comment: @avp но вообще суть ответа "спрятать учетку на клиенте - не получится". Просто топикастер просил альтернативное решение.

Comment: Т.е. взломав клиента (у себя) пользователь сможет независимо от приложения исполнять только те запросы, что зашиты в приложении?

Comment: @avp да, примерно так. правда, в случае того же SQL под винду обычно используют windows auth / разделение прав уже на стороне SQL Server - но это надо уметь настраивать, да и решение специфическое для MS SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Можете хардкодить в программе шифрованные строки Ваших учетных данных любым симметричным криптостойким алгоритмом, к примеру криптопровайдер `AES(128/192/256)`. В `App.сonfig` либо при запуске программы запрашиваете переменную-ключ. Пользователь вводит ключ, вы раскодируете учетные данные и логинитесь на сервере. Аутентификация на сервере пройдет успешно только при полном соответствии ключа, в противном случае расшифрование даст просто набор рандомных символов. Такой способ безопасен при декомпиляции, так как логин и пароль зашиты в виде шифрованного текста. Даже при успешной декомпиляции восстановить исходные данные (логин и пароль в открытом виде) по шифрованному тексту без  наличия ключа - крайне трудоемкая задача.

UPD:

Вообще, хранение на клиенте подобных данных - крайне не рекомендуется. Так как это требует впоследствии защищенного канала для пересылки этих открытых расшифрованных данных на сторону сервера.

Самый надежный способ - всю логику авторизации доверить серверу, а по сети передавать только некую отчужденную от самих данных информацию, преобразовав которую по некоторой логике, сервер сможет удостовериться в том, что вы тот, за кого себя выдаете.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55063/discussion-on-answer-by-vladimir-komarov----net---).

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам поможет [Data Protection Application Programming Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms229741(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Нет, не поможет. Это способ защитить данные текущего пользователя от других пользователей. А топикастер спрашивает про защиту (скрытие) данных от текущего пользователя.