# Как организовать авторизацию и аутентификацию в WPF приложении?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sql-server, безопасность

Делаю акцент на WPF, потому что обычно кидают статьи по безопасности в ASP.NET, но там вроде своя кухня. Есть база данных, в ней, если грубо округлять, есть 2 таблицы, Users и таблица с данными, в таблице с данными есть столбец UserID и внешний ключ. Клиентская часть представляет собой WPF приложение, есть форма входа и форма создания аккаунта. Интересует где и в каком виде хранить данные пользователя на клиенте, как и чем шифровать, как и по какому протоколу передавать эти данные, непосредственный процесс проверки данных пользователя и.т.д. В первую очередь интересует процесс авторизации через логин и пароль, которые создают сами пользователи.

Comment: Через токены...

Comment: Ребята с конфы по C# в телеграме предлагали запилить WebAPI на стороне сервера и организовать авторизацию через какой то AccessToken. Загуглил, смысл там следующий. На серверной стороне создаются два сервиса, сервис авторизации и сервис доступа к данным. WPF приложение обращается к сервису авторизации и в зашифрованном виде по защищенному каналу передает логин и пароль, тот в свою очередь сверяет это все с тем что храниться в БД и отправляет клиенту в ответку AccessToken. Клиент этот AccessToken передает сервису доступа к данным и тот в свою очередь уже предоставляет данные.

Comment: Как я понимаю AccessToken в данном случае - это некий паспорт, который дает доступ к пользовательским данным. А теперь кто бы кинул статью (можно и на английском) про это или пример кода.

Comment: AccessToken это для совсем "взрослых" проектов. Можете попробовать поискать на гитхабе примеры.

Answer (score 1):

[Связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/636651/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-net-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5/637249#637249).

Хранить учетные данные на клиенте ***крайне нежелательно***!
При регистрации пользователя можете сохранять логин и пароль в вашей БД в виде свертки, к примеру [MD5](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0ahUKEwjY0eT84_bSAhVmSZoKHRBcAksQFghDMAY&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fru-ru%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.security.cryptography.md5(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNHcZqsr9PVJwI6MB7FNTAlwaILMyA&sig2=aXtGHsPvcb5u6CBoqQyFag). При авторизации берите свертку от логина и пароля и по сети передавайте уже непосредственно их. Соединение с MSSQL поддерживает SSL. Даже если заснифают и будут ломать шифрование, то выловят свертки, а не сами учетные данные. Также можно предусмотреть принудительную смену пароля (раз в неделю, к примеру)

Answer (score 1):

У вас толстый клиент. Всевозможные системы авторизации для веб-клиентов вам не подходят. Там свои библиотеки, свои протоколы, для поддержки которых придется сильно усложнить приложение.

Естественно, авторизация должна быть своя, а не базы данных. И дело тут вовсе не в безопасности, а в удобстве управления пользователями и их правами. Что делать если вдруг в таблице хранится несколько сущностей, как дать доступ только на одну из них, если права на уровне БД? Как дать доступ на форму ввода (нет соответствующей сущности в БД) и т.д.

Теперь по поводу алгоритма логина пользователя. Достаточно защищать только пароль. Идея в том, чтобы не хранить пароль в чистом виде ни на клиенте, ни на сервере БД (его тоже можно взломать). Имейте в виду, что существуют сервисы преобразования md5 в строку. Возможно стоит использовать какой-нибудь алгоритм получения хэша посложнее. Но и md5 тоже прокатит.

Конечно можно подслушать хэш с другого компьютера. Но чтобы защититься от этого, можно привязать пользователя к IP-адресу. Т.е. знание логина и пароля от другого пользователя становятся бесполезны. Естественно, этот вариант не подходит, если у пользователей нет фиксированных мест.

Answer (score 0):

Для полной безопасности хранить данные при подключении в самом клиенте и конектится на прямую к базам безсмыслено. Я бы делал запрос к какому нибудь скрипту php который лежит на сервере, этот скрипт уже делал бы запрос к бд и полученные данные от бд отправлял клиенту.

Answer (score 0):

При регистрации:

1. Пользователь данные для регистрации
2. Вычисляют хэш-значение пароля (использовать стоит криптостойкие алгоритмы хэширования).
3. Передавать следует по любому шифрованному каналу. Можете использовать WCF.

На клиенте хранить учётные данные лучше в зашифрованном виде, так как хранение просто в отдельном файле логина и хэш-значения - большой риск.

В идеале - пользователь сам вводит учётные данные каждый раз в новой сессии.

Работа напрямую с БД - не самый лучший вариант. Лучше всего написать Серверное приложение, которое будет "прослойкой" между клиентом и БД. Это поможет избежать многих проблем и улучшить безопасность.